# kamon with statsd backend: histogram median aggregation is wrong

Tags: statsd, kamon

I use kamon for a scala project and collect some metrics with `Kamon.histogram`. I use stastd + graphite + grafana as the backend. I record about 200 events per second.
The statsd has the flushInterval of `flushInterval: 10000,` (10 seconds), and kamon has `tick-interval = 10 seconds`.

I noticed that the median (and all the other percentiles) are computed wrong. Furthermore, when I change the `tick-interval` of kamon to 1second, the median value changes, becoming closer to the correct one (but still not quite).

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bug in `kamon-statsd`: https://github.com/kamon-io/kamon-statsd/issues/6